# Open more than one stream between socket and serversocket

Tags: java, sockets, stream, serversocket

I'm creating a simple chat in Java, and it works. I just have a problem when a client close the connection, because it continue to appear online. This is because there's no a way to know when a stream is closed.

I searched on google and any solution has not resolved my problem, so I want to send a `boolean` each 300ms and, if I don't receive any answer or I get an error, I can close the connection server side.

The problem is that there's a conflict in the stream, I can't know if I'm reading a `boolean` or a text, so sometimes my `CheckConnection` class try to read a string and my `SocketHandler` class try to read a `boolean`, and I receive an error. 
I use the class `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to read and write into the stream.

It's my first server application and I don't know very much about it, I don't know if it's possible open more than one stream or if there are other solutions, so I'm asking you. What may I do?

**PS**: I tried to create a `PrintStream` and execute the `checkError()` method, but it returns always false, even if I close explicitly all the streams client side. Thank you.

Comment: its probably good idea to show some codes, I have no idea how you did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use text as this is simpler to work with to start with.

- treat any message as a heartbeat. If you get data, the connection is still good.
- treat a heartbeat as a string and chat as a string. it's all a String so you don't need to worry about what it is.
- check a stream is open by attempting to read from it and expecting you will get something within a timeout period.

You can use BufferedReader, or Scanner to reads the text. You can user BufferedWriter to write the text.

In your string you can create a simpler protocol like this.

```
say [to-whom] [message ...]
```

for the heartbeat you can have

```
hb
```

or

```
heartbeat
```

or

```
say nobody hi
```

You might add commands like

```
login [user] [password]
```

and

```
kthxbye
```

To decode the message, look at the first word and you know it's purpose and then read the second word for `say` and the rest of the string is the message.

To test the protocol, you can `telnet` to the port and type in stuff to the server directly.  You don't even need to write a client to start with.